# concept of record vs request vs batch in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I've seen these terms used interchangeably while reading parameters of producer API. So, do these terms refer to same thing or is there any conceptual difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A record is the data or message to be sent.

A batch is a fixed number of records to be sent together.

A request is sending multiple batches to the broker so that the broker writes them to the topic.

Comment: Kafka sends a batch as soon as batch.size of bytes is collected or linger.ms tims has passed. then how come there can be multiple batches in a single request? or does it mean that the kafka is ready to send a batch for one partition, batches for other partitions would be closed and sent in the same request?

Comment: I have the same question.So, have you found an anwser?  @Anatolii Stepaniuk

Comment: docs say : Requests sent to brokers will contain multiple batches, one for each partition with data available to be sent.